# How can I strip out default markup for a text field?

Tags: entities, theming

I have created text fields for first name and last name (which i need as separate fields so i can sort by last name when needed) but the default markup is so cumbersome! they each are nested in 3 divs, and all I want to do is display as a typical manner, ie. Firstname Lastname

How can I strip out the default markup for these 2 fields only? creating a field override template doesn't seem like a good idea, or is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several ways to skin this cat. You can use a custom tpl.php as suggested, or, you can also explore some contrib modules such as display suite or fences.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's the best idea--that is exactly what template overrides are for. Figure out a tight override for it. Something like `field--first-name.tpl.php`. In there keep just the mark up you want. Probably something like:

`<div class='firstname'><?php echo $variables['first-name']; ?></div>`

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!theme!field.tpl.php/7